# Cypress - waiters for dependent sub elelemnts

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cypress

I'm stuck with problem in cypress
there is dynamic DOM:

```html
<div class="Table">
  <div class="Item">
    <div class="Name"> Name1 </div>
    <div class="Color"> Color1 </div>
    <div class="Add"> Add </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item">
    <div class="Name"> Name2 </div>
    <div class="Color"> Color2 </div>
    <div class="Add"> Add </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

elements `.Item` appear dynamically how I can wait until "Item" with

```html
 <div class="Name"> Name3 </div>
 <div class="Color"> Color3 </div>
```

appear in this list and get `.Item` via Cypress

---

DOM before
before

```html
<div class="Table">
  <div class="Item">
    <div class="Name"> Name1 </div>
    <div class="Color"> Color1 </div>
    <div class="Add"> Add </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

after

```html
<div class="Table">
  <div class="Item">
    <div class="Name"> Name1 </div>
    <div class="Color"> Color1 </div>
    <div class="Add"> Add </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item">
    <div class="Name"> Name1 </div>
    <div class="Color"> Color2 </div>
    <div class="Add"> Add </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```html
<div class="Table">
  <div class="Item">
    <div class="Name"> Name1 </div>
    <div class="Color"> Color1 </div>
    <div class="Add"> Add </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item">
    <div class="Name"> Name2 </div>
    <div class="Color"> Color2 </div>
    <div class="Add"> Add </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or it could be

```html
<div class="Table">
  <div class="Item">
    <div class="Name"> Name1 </div>
    <div class="Color"> Color1 </div>
    <div class="Add"> Add </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Item">
    <div class="Name"> Name2 </div>
    <div class="Color"> Color2 </div>
    <div class="Add"> Add </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

need to wait second row appear by Name and Color

Comment: can you decorate your DOM with dynamic attribute values like cy-data="blah" to assist testing... then you can wait on an attribute selector

Answer (score 4):

The `cy.contains()` will wait for the new `<div class="Item">`

```
cy.contains('div.Table div.Item', 'Name2', {timeout:6_000})
  .should('contain', 'Color2')
```

This specifies both Name2 and Color2 child elements exit in the one Item parent element.

Since it's asynchronously loaded, add a timeout that is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Since `class="Item"` is the common factor, use a `cy.get()` with retry on the count of it.

```js
cy.get('.Item').should('have.length', 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

on npm there is a package named cypress-wait-until that should work fine

**Installation**

```
npm i -D cypress-wait-until
```

**Import**

```
import 'cypress-wait-until';
```

**Usage**

Refere to [the official npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until)